# Larger text in file/folder listings in Springsource Tool Suite

Tags: eclipse, osx-mavericks, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

In Springsource Tool Suite 3.6.2RELEASE or STS, which is a build of Eclipse 4 with the Spring Tools already present, **I'd like to make all the text bigger in the GUI**, not only in editors which is easily done in the Preferences >> General >> Appearance >> Colors & Fonts, but **also in the files and folder names** in the Project Explorer, the Package Explorer and so on.

In the file STS.ini (Same function as eclipse.ini) I removed the row

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
```

but I don't notice a difference in the STS interface.

**How do I get to the settings of the file and folder listings?**

I'm on OS X Mavericks 10.9.5 and using Java 7.

Comment: this setting is coming from the system and is not configurable from within Eclipse as far as I know. Removing the option that you mentioned causes the font in the package explorer to increase in size, but I am not aware of any other solution. Sorry...

Comment: Thanks for the response, Martin. With "the system" here do you mean the OS or the JVM? Both in the OS and in the JVM there are font settings then somewhere, no? I don't fully understand why the setting is inherited for those listings if editors for instance are not.

Comment: It looks like Eclipse 4 has added some capabilities to style the package explorer, including the font size: https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CC8QFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.isl8.com%2F2013%2F11%2Fchanging-file-explorer-font-size-on.html&ei=SlRzVJnkEov2O_HqgLgE&usg=AFQjCNEKD3dWAmMeJKlvhZ6mPtKeu32clw&sig2=9djmSCvCf-5xojNzJ5TFVA